# Python percentile rank of a column, grouped by multiple other columns

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

I would like to group a pandas dataframe by multiple fields ('date' and  'category'), and for each group, rank values of another field ('value') by percentile, while retaining the original ('value') field.

I have attempted:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['date', 'category'])['value'].rank(pct=True)
```

But this returns only percentiles for the 'value' field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need assign `Series` to new column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'value':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'category':[5] * 6,
         'date':list('aaabbb')
})


df['new'] = df.groupby(['date', 'category'])['value'].rank(pct=True)
print (df)
   value  category date       new
0      1         5    a  0.333333
1      3         5    a  0.666667
2      5         5    a  1.000000
3      7         5    b  1.000000
4      1         5    b  0.666667
5      0         5    b  0.333333
```

Alternative with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(new= df.groupby(['date', 'category'])['value'].rank(pct=True))
```